# Move camera on a straight path while on a Z rotation

Tags: camera

I'm working on a project and my camera is at a 45 degree angle on the Z axis. I want to do a simple push in pull out to my object with the camera on a straight path, but I can't seem to get it right. Is there anything I can do here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set transform orientation to local.

That way Blender will treat local transforms such as the 45-degree as a default value.

[image]